# Not getting report of TestNG in ReportNG

Tags: selenium, report, automated-tests, testng, reportng

I am executing testng in eclipse and I want generate the report in reportNG. For that I have inlcuded guice-3.0,reportng-1.1.3,velocity-dep-1.4 jar files and added listeners in xml file Also I have disable the default TestNG listener in eclipse.
After all that I am not getting the report in ReportNG. What else I have to do?

This is the xml code....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">  

<suite name="Registration" verbose="1" preserve-order="true">

<parameter name="Suitename" value="Registration" />

   <listeners>
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
     <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" />
  </listeners>

 <test name="Search">
    <classes>
    <class name="com.tcs.medmantra.reg.Search"/>
  </classes>
 </test> 

</suite>
```

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You have to first run the tests by running the `testng.xml` as `TestNG suite`.
2. Then after that refresh the project.
3. Now goto the `test-output` folder `-->html-->index.html (Open with Web Browser)`.