# Selenium Java (maven project): TestNG results differs from ReportNG

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, reportng

I tried running `testng.xml` and the results were:

> ===============================================
>
> **Default test**
>
> Tests run: 14, Failures: 6, Skips: 0
>
> **Default suite**
>
> Total tests run: 14, Failures: 6, Skips: 0
>
> ===============================================

Now, I disabled deafult TestNG listener and added ReportNG listner in `testng.xml`. The `testng.xml`. looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name=".URL_Daily" />
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Following the steps, I added `velocity`, `guice` and `reportng` dependencies in maven's `pom.xml`.

Upon executing the testsuite `testng.xml`, following folders were created (marked in red box).

[image]

Upon opening `index.html` the results are like this:
[image]

As expected, an output folder should have been created by ReportNG which is not noticed in my scenario. Secondly, the results are different.

In addition, the report `index.html` doesn't look how actually it should be. Can somebody tell what's wrong?

Some details for your reference:

OS: Windows 7

Guice.jar version: `guice-4.1.0`

ReportNG Version: `reportng-1.1.4`

Velocity version: `velocity-dep-1.4`

TestNG Version: `testng-6.11`

Selenium Version: `selenium-java-3.5.3`

Eclipse: `eclipse oxygen`

My test case is as follows:

```
public class MwSites {
WebDriver driver;

@BeforeTest     
public void setup ()    
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Automation\\Drivers\\Selenium Drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("test-type");
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");  
    options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info"); 
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
    options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@AfterTest
public void Quit () throws InterruptedException
{
    driver.quit();
}

@Test(priority = 0)     
public void MI_Demo () throws InterruptedException
{
    driver.navigate().to("http://demo.movingwalls.com/mi/#/login");
    Assert.assertEquals("Login", driver.getTitle());
    if (driver.getTitle()=="Login"){
        System.out.println("Failed to access MI in demo environment");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("MI is successfully accessed in demo environment");
    }
}
```

Comment: have you configured the testng execution to build reports in a custom way? Would be better is you share your configurations used for the above.

Comment: I hope your current [workspace is same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7036722/1746118) as the shared directory. And you have tried [refreshing the folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20968295/1746118) as well?

Comment: Yes, it's the same workspace. Keenly cross-checked and re-verified every bit of configuration. Refreshed folder everytime prior execution.

Comment: In that case, could you share a reproducible code for this and also update the question with the versions of libraries in use and if relevant the OS you're testing this on.

Comment: @nullpointer Request done. I've mentioned the versions of libraries used.

Answer (score 1):

As your tests got skipped, you may want to check test results xml first to find out the root cause (exception).

On the other hand, I'm just wondering what's the initial intention of using a library, which is not maintained for 4 years? ReportNG is dead. It's a fact. And if you take a look at its sources, you'll see which TestNG version it uses (6.8). You could easily assume that its reporter is based on old TestNG API.

When you add TestNG 6.11 as a dependency, the probability of a jar hell occurrence is quite high. And I wouldn't be surprised, if it's a root cause of your issue.

If you haven't decided which reporting system to use yet, I'd recommend to take a look at a modern [Allure 2](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2) framework.

Otherwise, just check a stacktrace first to understand the root cause of your issue.

Comment: Using Allure 2 is an alternative. Thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't solve my problem. As per my management's request, I'm bound to use ReportNG only.

Comment: @Sanchit ok, but you haven't posted any stacktrace yet. So how would you expect people guess the root cause?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. It's working for me but the results are not as expected. As I have explained above. If there was an error, surely I would have provided stacktrace.

Comment: @Sanchit as far as I can see, you expect getting 8 passed and 6 failed scenarios. When you added ReportNG, you got 14 skipped tests (that's probably not expected, correct?). Tests can't be skipped without any reason. And even if you don't see any exception in html report, it's definitely present in one of test results xml files generated in `test-output` folder. So my suggestion is to check those xml files, and attach corresponding log to the original post to help others find out the root cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this using the specified versions.

By default the ReportNG reports are generated under `target/surefire-reports` folder as configured by surefire plugin. This is something that can be changed via surefire configuration.

You can add any test classes, but for the sake of ease, I am just including pom file and two sample classes that I have used.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rationaleemotions</groupId>
    <artifactId>46923243</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>46923243</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/velocity/velocity-dep -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.uncommons/reportng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                            <value>false</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

The test classes, that I used

```java
package com.rationaleemotions;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MwSites {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("test-type");
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--js-flags=--expose-gc");
        options.addArguments("--enable-precise-memory-info");
        options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
        options.addArguments("--disable-default-apps");
        options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void Quit() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void MI_Demo() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.navigate().to("http://demo.movingwalls.com/mi/#/login");
        Assert.assertEquals("Login", driver.getTitle());
        if ("Login".equals(driver.getTitle())) {
            System.out.println("Failed to access MI in demo environment");
        } else {
            System.out.println("MI is successfully accessed in demo environment");
        }
    }
}
```

```java
package com.rationaleemotions;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestClassWithMultipleResults {
    @Test
    public void testMethodWillPass() {
        Reporter.log("This test method will pass", true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodWillFail() {
        Reporter.log("This test method will fail", true);
        Assert.fail();
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "testMethodWillFail")
    public void testMethodWillSkip() {
    }
}
```

Suite xml that I used:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"/>
        <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.MwSites"/>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.TestClassWithMultipleResults"/>
        </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Here are the screenshots from the ReportNG reports

[image: Overview Summary]

[image: Overview Detail]

[image: Index Summary]

[image: Index Detail]

Comment: *I was able to resolve this using the specified versions* not sure what was it that you changed?

Comment: @nullpointer - That would depend on what was used to setup the classpath. I have used Maven.

Comment: Well the point is if you think that the classpath specification could be the cause, you should have pointed that as a comment(if to confirm) or else stated the details as to why it would cause so. Just repeating the content of the question seems plagiarizing.

Comment: @nullpointer - I would let the OP decide on whether the answer is plagiarizing or not.